# Writing data to SSISDB.Catalog.Executions

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to test a stored procedure which reads some values from `SSISDB.Catalog.Executions`. For achieving the same goal I want to write dummy data to `SSISDB.Catalog.Executions`. Is that even possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks about inserting into catalog.executions. The entire `catalog` schema is just views over the `internal` schema tables which have security role checks in place.

If you look at the definition for `catalog.create_execution` after doing some permission checks, it will use an CLR proc to insert into `internal.operations` to generate an ID and then the actual insertion into `internal.executions`

```
-- Parameters
DECLARE
    @folder_name nvarchar(128) = (SELECT TOP 1 F.name FROM internal.folders AS F ORDER BY 1)
,   @project_name nvarchar(128) = (SELECT TOP 1 P.name FROM internal.folders AS F INNER JOIN internal.projects AS P ON P.folder_id = F.folder_id ORDER BY F.name)
,   @package_name nvarchar(260) = (SELECT TOP 1 PKG.name FROM internal.folders AS F INNER JOIN internal.projects AS P ON P.folder_id = F.folder_id INNER JOIN internal.packages AS PKG ON PKG.project_id = P.project_id ORDER BY F.name)
,   @reference_id bigint = NULL
,   @use32bitruntime bit = 0
,   @execution_id bigint; 

DECLARE @caller_name internal.adt_sname = (SELECT USER_NAME());
DECLARE @caller_sid internal.adt_sid = (SELECT USER_ID());
DECLARE @created_time datetimeoffset;
DECLARE @return_value int;
DECLARE @operation_id bigint;
DECLARE @result bit;
DECLARE @environment_id bigint;
DECLARE @environment_found bit;
DECLARE @environment_name nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @environment_folder_name nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @reference_type char(1)
DECLARE @version_id bigint

SET @created_time = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET();
SET @operation_id = -1;

INSERT INTO
internal.operations
(
    operation_type
,   created_time
,   object_type
,   object_id
,   object_name
,   status
,   start_time
,   end_time
,   caller_sid
,   caller_name
,   process_id
,   stopped_by_sid
,   stopped_by_name
,   operation_guid
,   server_name
,   machine_name
)
VALUES
(
    200
,   SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()  -- created_time - datetimeoffset
,   20
,   0
,   N'Demo'  -- object_name - nvarchar(260)
,   1  -- status - int
,   SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()  -- start_time - datetimeoffset
,   SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()  -- end_time - datetimeoffset
,   @caller_sid
,   @caller_name
,   0  -- process_id - int
,   NULL  -- stopped_by_sid - varbinary(85)
,   N''  -- stopped_by_name - nvarchar(128)
,   NULL  -- operation_guid - uniqueidentifier
,   @@SERVERNAME
,   @@SERVERNAME
)

SELECT
    @operation_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT into internal.executions
(
    execution_id
,   folder_name
,   project_name
,   package_name
,   reference_id
,   reference_type
,   environment_folder_name
,   environment_name
,   project_lsn
,   executed_as_sid
,   executed_as_name
,   use32bitruntime
)
VALUES 
(
    @operation_id
,   @folder_name
,   @project_name
,   @package_name
,   @reference_id
,   @reference_type
,   @environment_folder_name
,   @environment_name
,   @version_id
,   @caller_sid
,   @caller_name
,   @use32bitruntime
);

-- Look at what I've done
SELECT @operation_id AS OperationId;
```